# Get a list of all symbols out of the QGIS Style Manger via PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, symbology, style-manager

I'am working on a plugin which is loading layers automatically. When the layers are loaded they should get categorized. I done it with svg files but i have more symbols in my Style Manager which I want to use for the categorization. Do anybody know how I can read all symbols out of the Style Manager? I use QGIS 3.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access the default style library via

```
QgsStyle.defaultStyle()
```

This gives you a QgsStyle object (see https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/other/QgsStyle.html). From there, you can call methods like

```
style=QgsStyle.defaultStyle()
style.symbolNames() # returns a list of symbol names
style.symbol('dash blue') # returns the symbol with name 'dash blue'
```